# JavaFx Tabpane opens new scene but first tab stays selected

Tags: java

I am a beginner to java FX and have a simple app with two tabs. When one tab is pressed it open another scene. The issue is that the first tab stay selected when the second scene is opened?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide some code example related to your issue

Comment: Hello Thank you for looking at my question. I have now solved the issue using  tabpane.getSelectionModel().select(0); . This selects the tab at the start of the init.